# Automating Attribute Table with Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I'm using QGIS 3.10.0 A Coruna.

I'm using the field Calculator for an equation which requires a variable (which I Type in manually) and a (fixed) value within the same attribute table. This variable is different for each feature, meaning I have to write the equation (for my example) 55 times.

I dont have a problem with that so far; however, if for any reason my fixed value should change, I would have to repeat the work with the field calculator over and over again. Is there a way where

1) I can see which equation I used in the first place and

2) where I can automatically update my results in the attributetable
    in case the fixed value changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If adding new fields to your layer is an option for you, you can do it the following:

1. Save your two values into the fields "fixvalue" and "varvalue"
2. Save your expression into a field ("expression") using the string indicator `'` (single quote) like this: `'("fixvalue" * "varvalue")'`

[image]

3. You can now calculate your result using the expression  `eval( "expression")`. The expression `eval()` turns a string into an expression.
4. The result

[image]

When you now change your fixed value by using field calculator -> update fields, you can easily recalculate your result by using the expression in #3 like this:

Update the fixvalue:

[image]

update the result:

[image]

the new result:

[image]

Comment: Instead of saving the fixed value in a field, you can save it as a [layer level variable](https://nyalldawson.net/2015/12/exploring-variables-in-qgis-pt-3-layer-level-variables/). That way you only have to change it in one place when you change the fixed value.

Comment: Thanks csk! I never used the layer level variables, it opens up many new possibilities.

Comment: MrXsquared, thank you for the elaborate answer! I didnt know the "eval" funktion - I might just be able to combine your and csk answers, so I dont have that many new fields!